# My code is not working properly,its logical error i think but i'm not getting it

Tags: c++, file-handling, dev-c++

It wasn't work properly as I want it to work .. According to my thinking,code which is given below is always true i don't know why but if-condition always true and number got matched .. Variable named as CNIC was globally declared like this(char CNIC[15])..

```
  private:
     char ch;
     char str[256];

     std::fstream file1;
  public:
    void verify()
    {
          cout<<"Enter your CNIC number for verifivation : ";
          for(int i=0;i<15;i++)                    
          {
                   CNIC[i] = getche();
          }

          file1.open("D:\\UOL\\OoP\\Nadra database.txt",ios::in);
          check = false;
          while(!file1.eof())
          {         
                file1.getline(str, 255);     
            if(check = strcmp(str, CNIC) == 0);
                 check=true;
          }
          file1.close();
          if(check)
          {
                 cout<<endl<<"CNIC number matched"<<endl;
                              }
          else
          {
                 cout<<endl<<"CNIC number did'nt match " ;
          }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please change your title to something relevant to the problem you're having. "My code is not working please help" is not a useful title.

Comment: Watch those semicolons. Carefully. (And get yourself an editor that indents for you.) Also, [`eof` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Add paranthesis and remove the `;` which end the statement: `if((check = strcmp(str, CNIC) == 0))
                 check=true;`

Comment: Guys,i'm just a fresher.Need some time to be like you.By the way thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You code contains a couple of errors.

The if statement is terminated by `;` so `check` will always be set to `true`

```
// the ';' terminates the if statement
if(check = strcmp(str, CNIC) == 0);
  // check will always be set to true
  check=true;
```

You need to remove the semicolon, change your code to:

```
if(strcmp(str, CNIC) == 0) {
  check=true;
  // my guess would be that you really like to break the loop here
  break;
}
```

I also must add a terminating null character to `CNIC` after your for loop, you will need to make room for 16 characters in the variable i.e `char CNIC[16];`  to make room for the null character:

```
for(int i=0;i<15;i++)                    
{
  CNIC[i] = getche();
}
// add null character
CNIC[15] = 0;
```

Comment: I changed the code as you said but else-condition is now working again and again ..

Comment: @AyubÎdréès - I also think you should add a null character to `CNIC`. Look at my edited answer above.

Comment: In file this line is written (PTI   1233542 1  Time of vote : 17:56:07) .. I want to search that 1233542 is already present or not,what shall i do to do that !! Do i split that data first then search for that number or is there any easy approach to tackle that problem ..

Comment: @AyubÎdréès - Start by accepting the answer if it solved you problem. Then you should create a new question since this don't seem to have anything to do with your previous question.